# Combining arbitrary property path, distinct, and count

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have the bellow SPARQL query and would like to get the sum of ?myInt for all the unique ?z values. Is it possible to express such a query in SPARQL 1.1?

```
SELECT ?z SUM(xsd:int(?myInt)) 
where{
?x property1+ ?y
?x property2 ?k
?k property3 ?z
?x property4 ?myInt
} group by distinct(?z)
```

I run this in Jena ARQ and get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " "sum" "SUM "" at line 1, column 11.
```

Here also an example data:

```
<http://a.com/6>  <http://aq.com/p>  <http://e.com/c5>.

<http://a.com/6>  <http://aq.com/q>  <http://a.com/5>.

<http://e.com/c5>  <http://aq.com/a>  <http://eoq.com/u1>.

<http://a.com/6>  <http://aq.com/num>  "10"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> .

<http://a.com/5>  <http://aq.com/p>  <http://e.com/c4>.

<http://a.com/5>  <http://aq.com/q>  <http://a.com/4>.

<http://e.com/c4>  <http://aq.com/a>  <http://eoq.com/u1>.

<http://a.com/5>  <http://aq.com/num>  "10"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>.
```

Comment: `GROUP BY DISTINCT(?z)` doesn't makes sense. You have to give the variables on which the result will be grouped.

Comment: And have to wrap the `SUM` class such that a variable name is known, e.g. `(SUM(...) AS ?sum)`. By the way, next time it would be good to have a SPARQL query with correct syntax (missing prefixes and dots, among others) such that people can test it, e.g. here: http://sparql.org/query-validator.html

Comment: And what's the idea of the first triple pattern? I mean, `?y` isn't used anywhere, so it would be enough to use `?x property1 ?y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't select expressions directly, you have to select them as variables. I.e., you need to do:

```
SELECT ?z (SUM(xsd:int(?myInt)) as ?sum)
```

This is a common mistake because some endpoints (e.g., the public DBpedia endpoint, which is running Virtuoso) *do* allow your original form, even though it's not legal SPARQL.

As mentioned in a comment, you should group by ?zero, not by distinct(?z).